# How to fix broken Wordpress domain

Tags: wordpress, url

In my Wordpress site's settings I changed the URL from http://www.lauraspantry.uk to http://www.allstaruhlmann.co.uk - stupid mistake, double so as I meant to add http://www.allstaruhlmann.com - I can now no longer access my site and get the following error

[image]

How can I resolve this and restore the original URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your  wp-config.php (via FTP or SFTP) :

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Where example.com is your correct url.

Further info:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Thanks for this.  It seems to have worked but I've lost all styling and just have plain HTML for my WP Dashboard.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you change it back in the Dashboard? First you have to remove the two lines from wp-config, and then (in the Dashboard) set the correct Url. (Otherwise the fields would be grayed out)

Comment: You're a legend.  Thank you.  I am also trying to post about transferring my site to another hosting provider but can't post for another hour.  Do I need to one click install Wordpress on the new host before I can transfer it or do I keep it blank?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you should create a new WP-instance and then move your DB/WP-installation (through backup) to the new instance.

Comment: I think that you do.  Just to clarify - does that mean install a new instance on the new host through one click installer and then 'restore' the new site through my backup?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go into your site's database and change siteurl in WP_Options. Usually you would use PHPMyAdmin. Available in your CPanel.